# Can the quotient by a nonabelian group yield an abelian singularity?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, invariant-theory, toric-geometry

Let $V$ be a complex vector space with a faithful linear action of a finite group $G$. Viewing $V$ as affine space (with coordinate ring $\mathbb{C}[V]$), the quotient $V/G$ is the affine variety with coordinate ring the invariant ring $\mathbb{C}[V]^G$. Typically, the image of the origin is a singular point of $V/G$. (Not always. If $G$ is a [reflection group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_reflection_group), the invariant ring is polynomial, so that $V/G$ is isomorphic with affine space.)

If $G$ is abelian, this singular point is said to be abelian. More generally, if $X$ is any complex algebraic variety and $p\in X$ is a singular point, it is an *abelian singularity* if $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}$ is isomorphic to $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{V/A,0}}$ for some abelian group $A$ and linear representation $V$ of $A$, where $0\in V/A$ is the image of the origin.

My question is this: suppose $G$ is not abelian. Can it still happen that the singularity at $0\in V/G$ is an abelian singularity in this sense?

If so, what's an example? (Even better, when in general does this happen?) If not, what's the proof?

**Addendum:** (3/26) I asked a [refinement](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234558/how-fine-an-invariant-of-a-representation-is-its-quotient-singularity) of this question on MO.

Comment: I guess you can take $G$ to act via its abelianization. Or do you want the action to be faithful? In that case, if I recall correctly, there is an example of an $A_5$-action which gives an abelian quotient singularity.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar - yes I was thinking of a faithful action, I'll adjust the question to make that clear. Do you know if the $A_5$ example is one of the irreducible representations?

Comment: I remember now where I saw this example. It is indeed given by an irr. rep'n. Have a look at the paper linked in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question can be found in Theorem 1.7 of Geraschenko and Satriano's paper "Torus quotients as global quotients by finite groups"; 
see

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4807.pdf

Comment: +1 This reference is extremely useful to me. I am not sure if it answers my question, partly because I think based on my own calculations that the variety $\mathbb{P}(V)/A_5$ is *smooth!* (I am going to reach out to Satriano with the hope of getting clarity on this point.) More fundamentally because Satriano and Geraschenko are considering the projective action so it doesn't pick up the singularity at the origin of $V/A_5$. But in any case it is tremendously useful - thank you!

Comment: I have had an email exchange with Satriano leading to the conclusion that $\mathbb{P}(V)/A_5$ is indeed smooth, but in any case your answer has led me to realize that I asked slightly the wrong question.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Good to hear you're getting closer to your goal.

Comment: I asked a refinement of the question on MO, here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234558/how-fine-an-invariant-of-a-representation-is-its-quotient-singularity Jason Starr's first comment seems to provide an example.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith that's good. You can post Jason's comment as an answer here, I guess.